# I am new to using antd library, How do I add an additional input/textbox here so that when I click + sign two input box appears

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want two input boxes to appear when I click on the `add` button,

[My try on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-mcnulty-71dbq?fontsize=14).

Answer (score 1):

You could just change the `Button` `onClick` handler from `add` to

```
() => {
    add();
    add();
  }
```

which just calls the add function twice.

In your case, try:

```js
<Button
  type="dashed"
  onClick={() => {
    add();
    add();
  }}
  style={{ width: "60%" }}
>
  <Icon type="plus" /> Add field
</Button>;
```